# How to export data from Cloud Firestore to file?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have an application programmed in Flutter and I use Firebase to collect some information sent by users.
The question is how can I transfer this information to my computer in the form of a file (JSON, TEXT, etc.) data like this picture:

[image]

Comment: have you tried the posted answer?

Answer (score 20):

Currently, Firestore does not support exporting existing data to a readable file but Firestore do have a managed [Exporting and importing data](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/export-import) that allows you to dump your data into a GCS bucket. It produces a format that is the same as Cloud Datastore uses. This means you can then import it into BigQuery.

However, community created a workaround for this limitation. You can use `npm` if you have installed it in your system. Below are the instructions to export the Firestore Data to `JSON` file using npm.

1. Generate a private key file for your service account. In the Firebase console, open Settings > Service Accounts.
2. Click Generate New Private Key, then confirm by clicking Generate Key.
3. Securely store the JSON file containing the key. You may also check this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-sdk).
4. Rename the JSON file to `credentials.json`.
5. Enter the below code to your console:

```
npx -p node-firestore-import-export firestore-export -a credentials.json -b backup.json
```

6. Follow the instructions prompted on your console.

You could also use this to import data to Firestore using below command:

```
npx -p node-firestore-import-export firestore-import -a credentials.json -b backup.json
```

Below are the results using `npm` from the package:

Firestore Collection:
[image: collection]

Console:
[image: console]

`backup.json`:

```
{"__collections__":{"test":{"Lq8u3VnOKvoFN4r03Ri1":{"test":"test","__collections__":{}}}}}
```

You can find more information regarding the package [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firestore-export-import).

Comment: Fantastic answer (I know we are not supposed to leave comments that just say that, but I can't double up vote it and it deserves something more).  Thank you!

Comment: thank you! , I have a question. If I use this package, can I extract 20GB of data as json at once?

Answer (score 2):

The package mentioned by @marc `node-firestore-import-export` in [above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70921800/4050261) has a flaw in case your database is very large.

This flaw is documented here
https://github.com/jloosli/node-firestore-import-export/issues/815

For this reason I would recommend using https://github.com/benyap/firestore-backfire

Answer (score 0):

I puzzled over this for a while before accepting that this super obvious functionality wasn't available.  found https://firefoo.app, which is a desktop GUI for Cloud Firestore. It allowed me to browse data in an intuitive way and download any document or collection as a json file in a variety of file formats. It worked exactly the way I expected. Only downside is that it costs $9 a month for a single license.

Answer (score 0):

[firestore-export-import](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firestore-export-import) helped me.

- create new directory and add:
- project key.json: project overview -> project settings -> service accounts -> firebase admin sdk -> generate new private key
- install firestore-export-import dependencie
- create a index.js with code below:
- run in terminal: node index.js

  const { initializeFirebaseApp, backup } = require("firestore-export-import");

const serviceAccount = require("./key.json");

```
const queryByName = (collectionRef) =>
  collectionRef.where("isSubscribed", "==", true).get();

// OPTIONS
const options = {
  // for query
  queryCollection: queryByName,
};

// Initiate Firebase App
const firestore = initializeFirebaseApp(serviceAccount);

// EXPORTING

// normal
// backup(firestore, "users", options).then((data) =>
//   console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
// );

// with query
backup(firestore, "users", options).then((data) =>
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This tool meets your needs.

https://github.com/tan-z-tan/PyFireConsole

You can use it something like this:

```
pip install pyfireconsole
```

```py
from pyfireconsole.models.pyfire_model import PyfireCollection, PyfireDoc
from datetime import datetime


class Journal(PyfireDoc):
    exercise_time: int
    exercises: list[str]
    start_datetime: datetime
    end_datetime: datetime

FirestoreConnection().initialize(project_id="YOUR-PROJECT-ID")

Journal.all().as_json(recursive=True)
#=> [{"id": "XXX", "exercise_time": 123, ...]
```

`recursive=True` it fetches nested Collections from Firestore recursively, which I think is handy.

Comment: please explicitly disclose your affiliation in your post. see [/help/promotion](/help/promotion). good job on showing how to use it to solve the problem!